# Custom circular tab bar icon?

Tags: swift, uitabbar

I am using `animated tab bar` library and it works great.
But I'd like to design a circular tab bar icon like the image below.
Even I used a larger pixels photo , it is resized to be like usual icons.

[image: Middle Circular Tab Bar Icon]

Comment: I thought about adding a circular button on the top of the tab bar :/

Answer (score 1):

@ober01 says [on this issue](https://github.com/Ramotion/animated-tab-bar/issues/115) that `animated-tab-bar` doesn't support this circular tab.